# Como gerar um arquivo pdf contendo as informações do certificado digital?

Tags: php, script, certificado-digital, openssl, fpdf

Tenho um sistema PHP que gera um pdf, e preciso utilizar o Certificado Digital do cliente para assinar esse documento. Estive lendo documentações, e vi que o [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) que utilizo ainda não dá suporte a este método, já o [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) dá.

Como o código é muito extenso, não tenho como mudar para outro componente. Já até consegui acessar os dados do certificado digital via `openssl_pkcs12_read` e assinar via `openssl_sign` porém não sei como gerar o arquivo pdf contendo as informações do certificado. Alguém tem uma alternativa ?

Comment: Você conseguiu Junior? Estou à procura disso também com o certificado A1.

Comment: não sei se isso vai ajudar mas encontrei [essa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100109/tcpdf-adding-digital-signature-to-the-created-pdf) no SO em inglês

Comment: Já efetuei este procedimento utilizando Java com a Biblioteca iText e funcionou perfeito. Caso lhe sirva pode dar uma olhada no iText in Action que tem exemplos.

Comment: Tenta usar o http://portablesigner.sourceforge.net/. É uma app java que você pode chamar a partir da linha de comando passando o parametros. Utillizamos ela pra poder assinar os PDFs.

Comment: Não rola uma resposta mais elaborada @cantoni?

Comment: Esperando aqui, até o último minuto :) Faltam 5. :)

Comment: @gustavox, posso elaborar uma resposta, mas pra isso preciso ver novamente como fizemos isso, tem muito tempo isso. No momento, tempo me falta. :-)

Comment: Ok @cantoni, quando der faz aí, e se a comunidade aprovar (+2 pelo menos) a recompensa virá em dobro (pq tem que ser no mínimo 200 agora rsrs, mas sem problema, tenho bastante interesse neste assunto, e acho que vai enriquecer bastante a comunidade - vide votos positivos na pergunta...). Abraços!

Answer (score 0):

Há como assinar pdf criado com o FPDF, ao invés do TCPDF

```
<?php
require_once('fpdf.php');

// crie uma instância do FPDF
$pdf = new fpdf();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 14);

// escreva algum conteúdo
$text = 'This document is created with FPDF on '
    . date('r')
    . ' and digital signed with the SetaPDF-Signer component.';
$pdf->MultiCell(0, 8, $text);

// Configura a saída do documento para ser string
$fpdf = $pdf->Output('', 'S');

require_once('library/SetaPDF/Autoload.php');
// or if you use composer require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

// crie um Http writer
$writer = new SetaPDF_Core_Writer_Http('fpdf-sign-demo.pdf', true);
// carregue o documento pelo seu caminho
$document = SetaPDF_Core_Document::loadByString($fpdf, $writer);

// crie uma instância da assinatura para o documento
$signer = new SetaPDF_Signer($document);

// configure algumas propriedades da assinatura
$signer->setReason('Demo with FPDF');
$signer->setLocation('setasign.com');

// crie uma instância OpenSSL
$module = new SetaPDF_Signer_Signature_Module_OpenSsl();
// configure o certificado de assinatura
$module->setCertificate(file_get_contents('certificate.pem'));
// configura a chave privada para o certificado de assinatura
$module->setPrivateKey(array(file_get_contents('private-key.pem'), 'password'));

// assine o documento
$signer->sign($module);
```

[Fonte](https://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-signer/demos/sign-pdf-created-with-fpdf/)